# Ruby : Find a Date in a array of strings

Tags: ruby, date

I am searching through an array of strings looking for a `Date`:

Is the method I'm using a good way to do it? 
***OR*** . . . is there a better alternative.

Perhaps a more *"beautiful"* way to do it?

```
    query = {'Hvaða','mánaðardagur','er','í','dag?','Það','er','02.06.2011','hví','spyrðu?'}

    def has_date(query)
        date = nil
        query.each do |q|
            begin
                date = Date.parse(q)
                query.delete(q)
                break
            rescue
            end
       end
       return date
    end
```

Comment: Are you just wanting one date or all possible dates? Will those dates have a specific pattern?

Comment: This function works. I get the first date that is in the array, which is what I want. I don't know the pattern of the date, as it may be in different languages. 
What I'm wondering is if theres a better way then catching the exception and brake'ing on success.

To me, this "feels" like goto in c. It works but it just feels dirty :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that in Ruby we use square brackets `[]` for array literals (curly braces `{}` are for Hash literals).

Here is a solution that will find *all* dates in the array and return them as strings (thanks @steenslag):

```
require 'date'
arr = ['Hvaða', 'er', '02.06.2011', 'hví', '2011-01-01', '???']
dates = arr.select { |x| Date.parse(x) rescue nil }
dates # => ["02.06.2011", "2011-01-01"]
```

Comment: Yup, this was exactly what I was trying to do.

Comment: Hmm, this looks better. But isn't it doing the same thing except for the brake ? and in a single line. What I'm wondering is, is it ok to use exceptions as a "main" part of the logic ? I thought that was a no no :)

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry about the curly braces, I just threw that in there to show an example input.  :)  Ruby is not my native language :D

Comment: @Bigginn: yes, using a break statement changes the behavior to return only the first date found, which is good if that's what you want.  As for exceptions, the Date constructor will always raise an exception on invalid input so we have to use a begin/rescue block, so it's not a case of "programming by exception".

Answer (score 0):

First you can try to validate the string, if it's a valid date format then you can parse it as a date:

```
query.each do |item|
  if item =~ /^\d{2}([-\\\/.])\d{2}\1\d{4}$/ then
    # coding
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the first date and you want to be strict about a valid date:

```
arr = ['Hvaða', 'er', '02.06.2011', 'hví', '2011-01-01', '???']

date = arr.detect do |x|  ## or find
  d,m,y = x.split('.')
  Date.valid_civil?(y.to_i, m.to_i, d.to_i)
end

p date #=> "02.06.2011"
```

(Date.parse is forgiving, it happily parses 02.13.2011)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to parse more types of dates, use [Chronic](https://github.com/mojombo/chronic)... I think it also has the side effect of not raising errors, just returns nil.

So if you want all valid dates found:

```
arr = ['Hvaða', 'er', '02.06.2011', 'hví', '2011-01-01', '???']
arr.collect {|a| Chronic.parse a}.compact
```

If you want the first:

```
arr.find {|a| Chronic.parse a}
```

and if you just want a true/false "is there a date here?"

```
arr.any? {|a| Chronic.parse a}
```